# which Maven(2) plugin to use with GWT 1.6?

Tags: maven-2, gwt, plugins, maven-plugin

There seems to be quite a lot of [confusion](http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Web-Toolkit/browse_thread/thread/791832a0e177e87e/6ece1fcd60b4824f?hl=en&ie=UTF-8&q=maven+plugin+gwt+1.6) regarding integrating **Maven** with **GWT 1.6,** as Google has changed the layout to "exploded war" format.  Which plugin are *you* using?  Does it have goals for hosted/compile?  Does it work "in place", writing output to `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF`, or does it use an external dir?  (I'm [not a fan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794839/gwt-1-6-project-war-layout-mixing-source-code-compiler-generated-artifacts) of having GWT-generated output appearing in my source tree).

If you have something working, POM snippets would be highly appreciated as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an article [here](http://blog.salvadordiaz.fr/2009/04/29/keep-your-source-tree-clean-gwt/) about how to use GWT 1.6, the Google Eclipse Plugin, maven 2, and the gwt-maven-plugin all together.

Answer (score 0):

I had this working by downloading the GWT Maven2 Starter App [here](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-maven2-starter-app/) and then changing the pom to use GWT 1.6.4 and it just seemed to work.

Comment: Hmm, that starter app says "Note this is for GWT 1.5.x.".  And the plugin that his site is using, maven-googlewebtoolkit2-plugin ominously has the following on its website: "NOTE: This plugin is being maintained, but new features are NOT being added here".  This doesn't really inspire confidence.  

Did you have any trouble switching to 1.6 given the new "exploded war" layout?

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the [gwt-maven2-starter-app](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-maven2-starter-app/) to use GWT 1.6.x and the codehaus maven-gwt-plugin.  Their work around is to deviate from the maven convention and to use the 1.6 standard /war directory inplace (instead of src/main/webapp) for webapp artifacts and GWT generated output (which you should add to .svnignore).